# Thunderbird: create message filter based on email name/author in 'From' header

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-filter

Version 91.12.0

The TB 'From' header on emails displays text (name/author) followed by
the sending email address enclosed in angle brackets, e.g.,
"babe ruth br@hof.com"

I can create a message filter rule: 'From contains @hof.com' and my
chosen action is performed as expected.

If I try to create a message filter rule: 'From contains babe' my chosen
action is not performed.

Is there any way to create a filter based on the name/author portion
of the 'From' header?

Comment: I have such filters and they work perfectly fine. Do you have a recent version of TB?

Comment: OP notes issue self resolved and has no indication of the cause of the issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP notes the issue self resolved and gave no indication of the cause.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It appears to work today. Guess I need more patience.

Issue appears to have self-resolved. No indication of the cause nor the fix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not an answer. It is a statement that the issue is no longer happening. You can just close your own question as it self resolved and there's no solution involved.